# Paint element of the same type together in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I would like to paint in a secuence of tiles the small tiles together in a couple.
paint big tile before a small tile until we have two small tiles.
but the json can be disordered.
Example:
[image]

javascript:

```
    var explora = angular.module("explora", ['ngSanitize']);

    explora.controller("exploraController", function ($scope) {


        $scope.pois = [
            {
                "cardSize": 0
            },
            {
                "cardSize": 1
            },
            {
                "cardSize": 1
            },
            {
                "cardSize": 1
            },
            {
                "cardSize": 1
            },
            {
                "cardSize": 0

            },
            {
                "cardSize": 1

            },
            {
                "cardSize": 0

            },
            {
                "cardSize": 1


            }
        ];


    });
```

html:

```
<body ng-controller="exploraController">

    <div ng-repeat="poi in pois" ng-class="poi.cardSize ? 'small' : 'big'"></div>

</body>
```

css:

```
    .big{
        width: 96%;background-color: cornflowerblue;padding: 1%;margin: 2%;height: 5rem;
        clear: both;
    }
    .small{
        width: 45%;background-color: yellowgreen;padding: 1%;margin: 2.3%;height: 5rem;
        float: left;
    }
```

Comment: Do this reordering in controller, views cannot be that smart.

Comment: use a custom filter.